# Private Message to User via Web API, not RTM API on Slack

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

Is there a way to post a message via the web API as a bot user? Right now it seems the flow is to use as_user=False and set channel to @username that you want to send it to.

However, if I'm not using RTM, is there a nice way to send a direct message as the bot itself?
https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you use the `bot_access_token` that you receive after installing your Slack app to the team with the `bot` scope when invoking the API method [chat.postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage), the direct message will come from your bot user. `as_user` has to be `false`, which is the default.

See [Using Oauth 2.0](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth) section "Bot user access tokens" for an example of how to get the `bot_access_token`.

Comment: Is this only when using a slack app? I'm using a bot access token from a Bot User I created manually for my Slack and when I post a message with the Web API it's coming from "SlackBot" rather than the bot user I created.

Comment: yes, its in the "slackbot" channel. But the message itself will come from the bot_user. Not sure if its possible to have direct message channel with the bot user.